# Help on Constructing a Carmichael number from an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

A quick definition of a Carmicheal number:

A composite integer $n$ such that all integers $a$ relatively prime to $n$, it is true that $a^{n-1}$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod n$ (Composite numbers satisfying [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) whenever $\gcd(a, n$) $=$ $1$))

I am trying to construct a Carmichael number from scratch using algorithm C from [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-214/S0025-5718-96-00692-8/S0025-5718-96-00692-8.pdf) on page 825. Reference:

(Copied directly)

Algorithm C
C1 [Start]. Choose an appropriate product of prime powers $\Lambda \leftarrow q_1^{h1} q_2^{h2} ...q_r^{hr}$ (with $q_1 = 2$ and $hj > 0$ for all $j$).

C2 [Combine qj ]. Build all
p(α1, α2,...,αr) $\leftarrow 2^{α1} q_2^α2 q_r^{αr} +1$ 
with $1 ≤ α1 ≤ h1$ and $0 ≤ αj ≤ hj$ for $j > 1$.

C3 [Collect admissible factors]. Put all p(α1, α2,...,αr), if they are prime and
different from every qj , j = 2, 3,...,r, into the set S. If Λ + 1 ∈ S, set
S←S $\backslash$ {Λ+1}. [In this case, every Carmichael number with λ(N)=Λ
found by the algorithm can be multiplied by Λ+1 to give another Carmichael
number, see property (b).] Build $s ← (Q_p ∈ S_p) \bmod Λ$. If s = 1, set T ← ∅
and continue with C5.

C4 [Find T ]. Find a set T ⊂S with Q
p∈T p ≡ s (mod Λ).
C5 [Construct Carmichael number]. Now
N = Y
p∈SrT
p
is a Carmichael number.

I started with the product: $2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61$ $=$ $1251804180$ $=$ $P-1$. Now let $2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61+1$ $=$ $1251804181$ $=$ $P$ is a prime. I am confused at step two since the only prime factors in the subset $S$ are $P$ and those dividing $P-1$. Can someone help finish the construction. Thanks in advance.

I am unsure weather $P$ | $N$ where $N$ is our resulting Carmicheal number. I know from reading the .pdf file that when $q$ and $nq+1$ are primes, a Carmicheal number is never divisible by both $q$ and $nq+1$. So if $N$ | $P$ then $N\nmid (2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 31, 59, 61)$.

Despite the post earlier, I chose 6 of 62 of the primes found by Joffan:

$D$ $=$ $4013*158357*241429*310931*347821*624031$ $=$ $290539349$ $\pmod {1251804180}$.

The modulo inverse of $D$ is $895667609$. Therefore finding a number $B$ with the 62 primes factors coprime to $D$ congruent to $895667609$ $\pmod {1251804180}$, $BD$ should result in a Carmichael number. Substantially adding prime factors to these gives me a $1$ in $1.25*10^9$ chance of a Carmichael number occuring.

What about choosing other sets, say $2^5*3*5*7*73*3084468319$ = $756558389284320$ $=$ $Λ$. $13*29*41*43*71*113*337*421$ $=$ $756558389284321$ = $Λ + 1$ is not prime, however it is a Carmichael number. Would that still give me the the additional Carmichael number, $p$($Λ + 1$) for every Carmichael number $p$ I construct with the set $2^5*3*5*7*73*3084468319$ $756558389284320$ $=$ $Λ$?

Comment: I don't understand why you chose 6 primes from the set of 62... you have to work with the whole set and gradually work through possible combinations of primes to *omit* from the 62, in order to bring the modulus of the result to 1 for each prime power in $\Lambda$. ~~~ You have chosen an unwieldy set of factors for $\Lambda$; the process gets very squeezed for the smaller primes.

Comment: Should I start with smaller primes then? I should multiply all of them together and take the result modulo $(2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61)$? and work from there. Then I would be removing factors instead of adding them.

Comment: No, the issue is actually that there are not enough options left to manipulate the smaller prime moduli. You could possibly improve that by increasing the exponent on the bottom three primes, say, $2^4 \cdot3^2 \cdot5^2 \cdot11 \cdot17 \cdot31 \cdot59 \cdot61$

Comment: This product $2^2*3^2*5^2*11*17*31*59*61$ $=$ $75108250800$, adding $1$ to that is $75108250801$ $=$ $43*6131*284897$  is not prime so this won't work with constructing two Carmichael numbers quickly.

Comment: Nevertheless it could work with constructing Carmichael numbers; you just wouldn't get the "bonus" numbers.

Comment: See above (my most recent edit to the post), I am unsure of the case handled with my new subset of primes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than addressing your example head-on, I'll illustrate the process with a really simple $\Lambda = 2^2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$

Then the even factors of $\Lambda$ are $ \{2,4,6,10,12,14,20,28,30,42,60,70,84,140,210,420\}$; adding one to each gives $ \{3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15, 21, 29, 31, 43, 61, 71, 85, 141, 211, 421\}$ then weeding out composites and factors of $\Lambda$ gives $ \{11, 13, 29, 31, 43, 61, 71, 211, 421\}$ and finally removing $\Lambda +1 = 421$, which happens to be prime, gives $ S =\{11, 13, 29, 31, 43, 61, 71, 211\}$ . I will explain later in the process why removing $\Lambda +1$ doesn't hurt our chance of finding Carmichael numbers.

Now according the overview, we find $\prod S \bmod \Lambda$, which is $311$. Since this isn't $1$, we can't just multiply all members of $S$ together and declare that we have found a Carmichael number. Note that keeping $421$ in set $S$ would have made no difference to this modular result.

So we need to find a subset of $S$, called $T$, that also has $\prod T \bmod \Lambda = 311$. Then we would know that  $\prod (S\backslash T) \bmod \Lambda = 1$ and the elements of $ (S\backslash T)$ mulitplied together will be a Carmichael number.

But for reasonably challenging numbers, we don't want to just go fishing around for a subset $T$ with a matching modulus, which is where the interesting part of the algorithm begins. Instead of trying to match one big number, we'll match a number of smaller numbers - in this case relative to four moduli, the prime (power) components of $\Lambda$ . So now each member of $S$ has a quad of residues associated with it:

$$\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{modulus:} & 2^2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \hline
11 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
13 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 6 \\
29 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
31 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
43 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
61 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
71 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
211 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\prod S & 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}$$

And without getting too deep into the process, we can work back across the values to match the $(3,2,1,3)$ of $\prod S$  with a subset. In this case $31$ will match the $7$ modulus, then we can choose from those elements with $p \equiv 1 \bmod 7$ to match the remaining requirements. Setting $T = \{31, 71, 211\}$ gives the required match here and so $11\cdot 13 \cdot 29\cdot 43\cdot 61 =10877581$ is a Carmichael number.

Note that the quad for $\Lambda+1=421$ is $(1,1,1,1)$, so it makes no difference to the process, whether included or excluded - so for the sake of simplicity, it is left to one side while the matching process goes on. Since, in this case, it is prime, we can get a *second* Carmichael number, $421\cdot 10877581 = 4579461601$ .

Comment: Okay, I see what you did there. Now suppose you had another set, say work with the divisors of $2820$ $=$ $Λ$  for instance. $Λ+1$ $=$ $2821$ $=$ $7*13*31$ is a Carmichael number, that would mean that we would get another Carmichael number for every other one that we construct.  They form the subset of primes {7, 11, 13, 31, 61, 283, 941}. Of this $38775580921$ = 7*11*31*61*283*941 is a Carmichael number. Now what is the case about the second additional Carmichael number, (Λ+1)*(7*11*31*61*283*941)?

Comment: Only valid if you can avoid the factors of the $\Lambda+1$ Carmichael number. In that case you had $7$ and $31$ in your constructed Carmichael and also as factors of  $\Lambda+1$. Carmichael numbers  have to be square-free.

Comment: Joffan, please see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009295/constructing-a-specific-carmichael-number-with-factors-of-the-form-2n3n-2 I am trying to accomplish a task on constructing a very specific Carmichael number.

Answer (score 0):

> I started with the product: $2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61$ $=$ $1251804180$ $=$ $P-1$.

Woah, where did $P$ spring from? $2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61$ $=$ $1251804180$ $= \Lambda$.

Now the candidate prime set is formed by taking every even factor of $\Lambda$ and adding one; if this value is prime, it is added to the candidate prime set.

> Now let $2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61+1$ $=$ $1251804181$ $=$ $P$ is a prime.

This is not essential to the method. You can ignore $\Lambda+1$ - whether it is prime or not makes no difference to the method or the potential for success in constructing a Carmichael number. If it happens that $\Lambda+1$ **is** prime, then any Carmichael numbers $c_j$ that you generate have a "free" additional Carmichael number, $(\Lambda+1)c_j$

There are $62$ primes in the candidate set for your starting product:

$$\{
7,13,23,67,103,311,331,367,373,661,683,709,733,1021,1123,1181,1831,1861,1871,3163,3541,3659,4013,4027,4093,6491,7789,8053,12037,13421,18911,19471,22067,23189,30091,41603,43189,56731,68443,107971,109741,158357,192883,241429,244733,310931,342211,347821,395891,624031,734197,1248061,1928821,2231381,2375341,3536171,3670981,4038079,4104277,6840461,8076157,250360837
\}$$

Comment: What about multiplying all $62$ prime numbers, and finding all $2^{62}$ divisors modulo ($2^2*3*5*11*17*31*59*61$)? then search for the result $1$. I know that seems complicated, but I can't think of any other way to complete this process.

Comment: Well, the paper gives the method. Essentially you break it down by the 8 component primes and try to bring all 8 moduli simultaneously to $1$ by omitting a few primes, step by step.

Comment: BTW did you understand how list of the 62 primes was produced?

Comment: The common property with all the primes $p$ on your list, $p-1$ divides $1251804180$. $p$ $=$ $1251804181$ should be included on your list too because it is prime and $p-1$ divides $1251804180$.

Comment: That gets discarded as per the algorithm. Not needed (and not helpful) to make a Carmichael but will give you a bonus Carmichael every time you find one. **"If Λ + 1 ∈ S, set S←S ∖ {Λ+1}."**